# “during his freshman and sophomore {year/years}”

Tags: plural-forms, singular, compound-subjects

Should ***year*** be singular or plural in the following example?

> As a bass fisherman, during his freshman and sophomore **year**, Bob was challenged by his lack of experience in the fishing arena but never gave up.

Answer (score 4):

Since the freshman year and sophomore year are multiple years, this takes the plural, so "freshman and sophomore years" would be correct. "[D]uring his freshman year and sophomore year" would also be fine, if slightly redundant, but would emphasise that each was a single year respectively.